# How do I group cells from multiple columns using the "group by" clause in a QUERY function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a data set with four columns of names and a single column of values. A specific name may appear multiple times per column and in any name column. Some of the cells in the name columns are also empty. It looks something like this:

| Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | Dorothy | Becky |  | 3 |
| Becky | Edith |  |  | 2 |
| Carl |  |  |  | 4 |
| Dorothy | Becky | Andy | Edith | 3 |
| Carl | Andy |  |  | 1 |

What I try to achieve is a single list where every name shows up only once with the corresponding values added up. Something like this:

| Name | Sum of Values |
| --- | --- |
| Becky | 8 |
| Andy | 7 |
| Dorothy | 6 |
| Edith | 5 |
| Carl | 5 |

So far, I have only been able to achieve this one name column at a time using the following function:

```
 =QUERY(Data!A2:E; "select Col1, SUM(Col5) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by SUM(Col5) DESC")
```

I can't figure out how to group cells from more than one column. I have tried to FLATTEN() the columns first, but I don't know how to do this *only* for the name columns while also keeping the corresponding value for each cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach (`non-query-based`)*

```js
=sort(map(unique(tocol(A2:D;1));lambda(Σ;{Σ\sum(index(if(A2:D=Σ;E2:E;)))}));2;)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know half the elements in that formula, but it works. Thanks a lot!